# Angular 12 laggy when live streaming huge data via socket

Tags: html, callback, angular12, lightstreamer

I have built an application streaming stock real time data connecting to lightstreamer and upon callback will trigger some typescript method to update the value and identify the html element and update the css class for color blinking to indicate value changes, however when the data changes is actively updating, the whole page became very laggy, and can't really subscribe to a lot data, as it will become laggy as well, any way to counter this situation?

Angular 12
nz-zorro
native html/css

Comment: Understanding that javascript is single thread queue system, so upon rendering UI, if massive update, it will definitely cause issue like lagging or high browser CPU resource, is there a way to counter this scenario for an Angular 12 project

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.